# Java: Do-while loop executing even if condition is false

Tags: java, loops, multidimensional-array, do-while

This is a word search program. The text it searches through is input and turned into a 2D array in another class.

This is the text the program is searching through:

```
10 //rows
15 //columns
fqexfecmxdvjlgu
cxomfslieyitqtz
nucatfakuxofegk
hfytpnsdlhcorey
pgrhdqsypyscped
ckadhyudtioapje
yerjodxnqzztfmf
hypmmgoronkzhuo
hdskymmpkzokaao
amuewqvtmrlglad
```

For some reason even if my terminating string `end` is typed in, it always goes into my `checkDown()` method and creates an out of bounds error. If I comment out that method and just execute the `checkRight()` and `checkDiagonal()` methods, everything seems to work fine. 
This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordSearch
{
    private char[][] array;
    private String targetWord;
    private int rowLocation;
    private int colLocation;

    public WordSearch(char[][] inArray)
    {
        array = inArray;
    }

    public void play()
    {
        do{
            for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++)
                {
                    System.out.print(array[row][col]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            System.out.println();
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
            System.out.println("What word would you like to search for? Type end to quit: ");
            targetWord = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Typed in: " + targetWord);
            System.out.println();

            compareFirst(targetWord);
        } while (!targetWord.equals("end"));

    }

    public void compareFirst(String inWord)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++)
            {
                if(array[row][col] == inWord.charAt(0))
                {

                    rowLocation = row;
                    colLocation = col;

                    suspectAnalysis();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void suspectAnalysis()
    {
        checkRight();
        checkDown();
        checkDiagonal();
    }


    public void checkRight()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < (targetWord.length()); i++)
        {
            if(colLocation + i > array[0].length - 1)
            {
                return;
            }

            else if(array[rowLocation][colLocation + i] != targetWord.charAt(i))
            {
               return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(targetWord + " found horizontally at row " + rowLocation + " and column " + colLocation);
        System.out.println();

        return;

    }


    public void checkDown()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < (targetWord.length()); i++)
        {
            if(rowLocation + i > array.length - 1 && colLocation + i > array[0].length - 1)
            {
                return;
            }
            else if(array[rowLocation + i][colLocation] != targetWord.charAt(i))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(targetWord + " found vertically at row " + rowLocation + " and column " + colLocation);
        System.out.println();          
    }

    public void checkDiagonal()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < (targetWord.length()); i++)
        {
            if(colLocation + i > array[0].length - 1 || rowLocation + i > array.length - 1)
            {
                return;
            }

            else if(array[rowLocation + i][colLocation + i] != targetWord.charAt(i))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(targetWord + " found diagonally at row " + rowLocation + " and column " + colLocation);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this happen when I comment out the `checkDown()` method? How can I fix it?

I'd appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Check the statement where you are getting the index out of bound exception. This type of exception isn't difficult to understand and fix!

Comment: @Bluasul can you add the code that you are using to test your WordSearch, what is your sample parameter for WordSearch constructor?

Comment: Is your problem as simple as knowing that a `do...while` loop will always execute the body of the loop before testing the condition in the `while` expression? That is, did you really mean to use a `while` loop (which tests the condition before deciding whether to execute the body of the loop)?

Comment: @alainlompo It reads  in data from a file, I'll add it to my question

Answer (score 0):

there a three circumstances which cause the fail:

1. Cause you use the do-while-loop, which checks his condition on the end of your loop, the programm is looking for the word "end before finishing
2. Your last row has an "e" (and thats your luck ;-) ). So your Analysis starts
   with row 9, col 3.
3. this condition:

   if(rowLocation + i > array.length - 1 && colLocation + i > array[0].length  - 1)

aka`if(9 + 1 > 9 && 3 + 1 > 14)`

gives back true && false => false 
causing an out of bounce in your next condition:

```
else if(array[rowLocation + i][colLocation] != targetWord.charAt(i))
```

aka

```
else if(array[9 + 1][3] != targetWord.charAt(i))
```

So change && to ||...

If you dont wont to check the word "end" exchange your do-while with a while(true) and check via

```
if(!targetword.equals("end"))
    break;
```

immediately after the scanner.